# Flickr JSON request doesn't finish

Tags: java, json, flickr

I am receiving a JSONException while trying to fetch a JSONObject from HTTP Get. I have a link that I know works, because I have tested it in the browser, but it doesn't work in Java, and it seems to be cutting short. A snippet from the end of the JSON text that I am receiving which I am pretty sure is the error is...

```
{"id":"1111111111", "owner":"11111111@A11", "secret":"a1a1a1...
```

.. where are the 1's and a's are their proper values. The ... ellipses at the end seem to indicate to me that it is cutting off?

Comment: Looking back I realize that I did not know that the ellipsis came from the IDE simply having a limit for how much text it displays of variables while debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I had to trim the "jsonFlickrApi(" from the beginning and ")" from the end of the response to have properly formed JSON.

Thank you all for the support.